# Increase shell buffer size in linux

Tags: linux

Its difficult to explain what I am exactly looking for, so let me try with an example..
Suppose i am finding  a file . But once my searching ends.. I am not able to scroll up and see all the 1000 lines. The size of the screen buffer is obviously limited. Is there anyway I can increase this size ?

Comment: What terminal program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't specify the terminal emulator you are using, in general terms you should look for the `scrollback` value, generally under the `Preferences` menu of your terminal emulator.  Could be under a `Scrolling` or `Profiles` sub-menu, as well.

For example, using `x-terminal-emulator`:

[image]

Similar menus and options should be available for other terminal emulators, like `PuTTY`, `GnomeTerminal`, etc...

---

Here's a similar thread in the AskUbuntu SE site:

- [How to see more lines in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385901/how-to-see-more-lines-in-the-terminal)

Comment: i am using bash terminal  Edit->Profilepreferences->Scrolling thank you for the support jim